# date-fns the reason npm build fails on Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, date-fns

This is the offending line of code:

```
<p>
   {(isSameDay(event.start, event.end)) ? `On ${format(event.start, 'LLL do')}`: `From ${format(event.start, 'LLL do')} to ${format(event.end, 'LLL do')}`}
</p>
```

I also tried:

```
<p>
    {(isSameDay(new Date(event.start), new Date(event.end))) ? `On ${format(new Date(event.start), 'LLL do')}`: `From ${format(new Date(event.start), 'LLL do')} to ${format(new Date(event.end), 'LLL do')}`}
</p>
```

and:

```
<p>
    {(event.start === event.end) ? `On ${format(new Date(event.start), 'LLL do')}`: `From ${format(new Date(event.start), 'LLL do')} to ${format(new Date(event.end), 'LLL do')}`}
</p>
```

The last one comes back false when it should be true, so it doesn't even matter that it fails the build.

I also uninstalled and re-installed date-fns.

I'm able to use `isBefore`, `isAfter`, `isToday` on a different page, so I have no idea why this line in particular is messing me up. Is my logic wrong? What am I missing? I love date-fns and would prefer not to use a different library, and I definitely don't want to deal with dates with vanilla JavaScript, but if I can't figure this out that's probably what I'll end up doing.

Here is the output when I try to build:

```
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - Skipping validation of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Collecting page data  
[==  ] info  - Generating static pages (20/175)undefined start
undefined end

Error occurred prerendering page "/vendor/events/EventsCard". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined
    at EventsCard (D:\boho\front\app\.next\server\chunks\9136.js:57:28)
    at d (D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:33:498)
    at bb (D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:16)
    at a.b.render (D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:42:43)
    at a.b.read (D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:83)
    at Object.exports.renderToString (D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:52:138)
    at renderPage (D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:596:45)
    at Object.ctx.renderPage (D:\boho\front\app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:53:30)
    at Function.getInitialProps (D:\boho\front\app\.next\server\chunks\6859.js:603:19)
    at Function.getInitialProps (D:\boho\front\app\.next\server\pages\_document.js:60:56)
info  - Generating static pages (175/175)

> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /vendor/events/EventsCard
    at D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\next\dist\export\index.js:487:19
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:60:20)
    at async D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:833:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:60:20)
    at async D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:707:13
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\next\dist\telemetry\trace\trace.js:60:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (D:\boho\front\app\node_modules\next\dist\build\index.js:77:25)
```

Comment: The issue isn't `date-fns`, it's the `event` variable that's undefined. Where is `event` coming from? Could you provide the code for `EventsCard` component?

Comment: You were right! I added code to check that event is defined and now everything works!